# Checkbox with text in same line using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, checkbox, itext, pdf-generation

I'm using ITextSharp.LGPLv2.Core 3.3.5 to generate a PDF. I need to create a checkbox with a label. The checkbox can be checked or not depends on the data when I generate the PDF.

Basically something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Currently I'm having two problems. First I don't know how to place content in the same line (I'm using a PdfPTable for this but the relative width makes hard to predict the result). Second, I don't know how to create the actuall checkbox. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you mean... Can you provide me some more info?